# Why there is no default text align to produce a line break inside a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, letters, tikz-node

Example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{letter}
\signature{Assistant director of the intergalactic unit}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\address{Gallifrey, Binary Start System}

\begin{letter}{My Neighbourhood \\ Me \\ EE.UU \\ Planet Earth, Solar System}

\opening{Dear sirs,}

This is a remainder for paying your intergallactic taxes, %etc...

\begin{tikzpicture}

%Beginning of the time line.
\draw[-] (0,0) -- (8.5,0);

\draw (7.5,-.1) node[below,align=center] {overdue compound interest \\ (+15 \%, september 2020)} -- (7.5,.1) node[above] {115 \%};

.
.
.
%etc...

%End of the time line

\end{tikzpicture}

\closing{Sincererly, The Gallifreyan Income Tax Department}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

To add a break line we need to `align`:

```
\draw (7.5,-.1) node[below,align=center] {overdue compound interest \\ (+15 \%, september 2020)} -- (7.5,.1) node[above] {115 \%};
```

Otherwise, no break line is resolved:

```
\draw (7.5,-.1) node[below] {overdue compound interest \\ (+15 \%, september 2020)} -- (7.5,.1) node[above] {115 \%};
```

Why there is no default text align?

Comment: Did you mean “alias” rather than “alienation”?

Comment: @HenriMenke No, text align.